# How to add button and tab after save data in admin form

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

In magento admin form Is that possible if status is applied than add button in form.

I mean in custom form there is one field status. Now i want to add button and new tab in form when status is applied.

Is that possible??

If yes than how can i do this?

[image]

Comment: @Marius Check it my update hope u can understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible,,,,

1. For tab you can put condition in

> app\code\CODE_POOL\NAME_SPACE\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\MODULENAME\Edit\tabs.php

in `_beforeToHtml()` method you can put your condition like

```
if($x==3){
 $this->addTab()
}
```

2. For button

> app\code\CODE_POOL\NAME_SPACE\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\modulename.php

in `__construct()` method you can put condition like

```
if($x==3)
{
$this->_addButton(.....)
}
```

For condition i think you can easily get from `Mage::register()`(from your controller)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with observers like this.

In your config.xml file add :

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
            <add_btn_delete_category_and_rewrite>
                <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>addBtn</method>
            </add_btn_delete_category_and_rewrite>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_block_html_before>
</events>
```

In your observer,

```
public function addBtn($observer) {

        $_block = $observer->getBlock();
        $_type = $_block->getType();

        if ($_type == 'adminhtml/catalog_category_edit_form' && CONDITION FOR ATTRIBUTE) { //adapt to the page you want to modify (here the category )


                $_block->addAdditionalButton('btn_name',  array(
                        'name' => 'btn_name',
                        'title'=>'Title',
                        'type'=>"button",
                        'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Button'),
                        'onclick'   => YOUR ACTION in controller,
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

You should be able to do something similar for the tab.